# Powering on with both Ethernet and WiFi disables WiFi adapter

Tags: wifi, ethernet

I have an Edimax EW-7811UTC WiFi adapter connected to my Pi 2 to connect it to the Internet.I also have connected it to my computer via Ethernet to share this connection.The problem is that when I power on the Pi with this setup, at a certain point the WiFi adapter LED starts blinking as if it were connecting to the network but then stops, and I have to unplug and plug it again for it to start working properly.This also happens sometimes when I power off/reboot the computer.

Comment: I also noticed this as I also use a EDIMAX. It looks like that's a bug of the adapter. It doesn't happen with my Fritz Adapter.

Comment: How have you configured networking? Without this we are working in the dark.

Comment: are you using a 2A power Adapter? because if not this will definitely cause a lot of problems for your wifi module

Comment: I'm using a 2.1A power adapter.My /etc/network/interfaces and wpa_supplicant.conf: http://pastebin.com/raw/MugHCmeT

Comment: I tried plugging my laptop when WiFi was connected and this was logged in syslog: http://pastebin.com/raw/0VgfW9ad

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved it, the file /etc/ifplugd/ifplugd.action that gets called by ifplugd when eth0 is plugged executes all files in /etc/ifplugd/action.d, including action_wpa, which "disconnects any                                                                 wpa-roam managed interfaces so that only one "roaming" interface                                                                          remains active on the system" if an ifplugd managed interface is brought up.

Since I wanted to be able to hotplug eth0, I just commented out these lines:

```
#if wpa_action "${IFACE}" check; then                                                                                               
#       wpa_cli -i "${IFACE}" "${COMMAND}"
#fi
```